# drawing a structure using x,y,z coordinates in php

Tags: php, opengl

I want to create a chemical structures using below x,y,z values. Those structures are needed to call from a PHP interface. At-no indicates atomic number of molecules included in it. eg : 6 indicates carbon, 7 indicates Nitrogen, 1 indicates Hydrogen. So based on coordinates values of C,N,H need to draw a solid sphere

Is it possible to draw a solid sphere in opengl and able to call it from PHP interface.

In opengl I cant able to draw a single solid sphere using some coordinates....

x,y,z coordinates values are

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------
    At-No                     X           Y           Z
---------------------------------------------------------------------
     6                   3.532210   -2.171743    0.921140
     7                   1.164869   -1.418981    0.782133
     1                   2.454732    2.332989   -0.907213
     6                  -3.246376   -1.047325   -0.602590
     6                  -2.620684    0.053348   -0.013310
     6                  -4.569969   -1.249720   -0.617858
     6                  -3.436335    1.003953    0.597094
     1                  -5.328079   -0.323336   -0.025131
```

Is There is any way to create structure from these coordinates in php or in opengl?

Comment: `$structure = [[1,6,0,4.475711,-0.327638,0.082195],[2,6,0,1.587359,0.477095,-0.094705],...];` - [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: Are you really sure you want to use PHP for that?

Comment: @kkanu would you please explain me why a 2d structure has three coordinates? :)

Comment: @kkanu You know that PHP can be used in CLI? So how you imagine 3D structure in CLI? Maybe try to generate image using http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php or http://php.net/manual/en/ref.image.php

Comment: @Justinas Thanks for your response................ Is there is any other language can be used for drawing structures.......... and also I want to access those structure through PHP interface....

Comment: Please help me.......Is there is any way to create a structure using above coordinates in any programing language and access those through a php interface............ Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is want you want, but you can use `gnuplot` to create a 3d visualization of the values:

*your.data:*

```
4.475711   -0.327638    0.082195
1.587359    0.477095   -0.094705
4.022151    0.936543   -0.444569
3.379861   -1.156311    0.521058
2.035736   -0.780174    0.439864
2.677913    1.310293   -0.523684
5.711393   -0.670462    0.158877
0.346038    0.825585   -0.179264
```

`gnuplot` commands:

```
gnuplot> set dgrid3d 30,30
gnuplot> set hidden3d
gnuplot> splot "your.data" u 1:2:3 with lines
```

This gives you something like this:

[image]

(I interactively change the camera position before taking the screenshot). You may play around with gnu plot and finally call it with from PHP to have an interactive solution.

Comment: Thanks for your response........ Is it possible to call these structure from php interface

Comment: Yeah, it is simply a call to an external program. You can use `shell_exec()` for example.You need to save gnuplot's output in a file then (check gnuplot's manual for that)

Comment: Thanks...... Is there is any other way to draw the structure using above coordinates....... either using OpenGl language or Php

Comment: There are some packages if you search on Google. This is one from PEAR is a bit old, but I would give it a try: http://kore-nordmann.de/projects/image_3d/index.html

Comment: If you want to display it in a browser, I would have a look at `d3js`

Comment: Yes, you can use it for that. I found some amazing examples in the web, but I never did it myself. I need to go to work now, probably I'll give an example later or in the evening.

Comment: You are welcome. What about this: https://plot.ly/javascript-graphing-library/3d-surface-plots/ ?

Comment: Actuallay i want to create a structure of chemical from these coordinates .......for example  First 3 values(x,y,z) indicate the position of carbon or any other molecule. In this way create the position of each molecules included in it.

Comment: Meaning a surface isn't what you want? Like this: http://threejs.org/examples/css3d_molecules.html ?

Comment: Yes I want to create such a type Structures (but not too complicated) and want to access those through a php interface